# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'path' of undefined - React

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, reactjs, map-function

I get stuck due to i can't solve the map function issue on React!
Well, i am using marvel api for getting picture, name, shortly information of comic strip.

How should i change the regarding code regulary. Can you guys know what the issue is? I am adding the screens at enclosed.

IMAGES OF ISSUE BELOW

[image]

[image]

[image]

THANKS

Comment: You should paste your code here, instead of images because it is easier for us to read/copy/paste it and help you. You can get 50 items of the array from the api result so I think you should check whether each item has a thumbnail object or not?

Comment: Yup, all items have thumbnal, as Dean James i added the console feels free to see datas now but it still has issue is it is not displaying the card info on front-end.

Comment: The codes look below now; useEffect(() => { axios({ url: "gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/…", method: "GET", }) .then( result => { setStateCharacters({ characters : [result], ...stateCharacters }) const getInfo = result.data.data.results; getInfo.map((result) => { console.log(result.thumbnail.path); }) }) },[])

Comment: const RenderCard = (card, index) => { return( <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key = { index }> { card.thumbnail && <Card.Img variant="top" src={${card.thumbnail.path}.${card.thumbnail.extension}} style={{ width:"100%", height:"200px"}} /> } <Card.Body> { card.name && <Card.Title>{card.name}</Card.Title> } <Button variant="primary">More Information</Button> </Card.Body> </Card> ) }

Comment: return ( <> <div className="card-heros__title">MARVEL CHARACTERS</div> <div className="card-heros"> I NEED TO CALL getInfo COMPONENT IN HERE THEN I WILL NEED TO WRAP IT WITH RenderCard then I BELIEVE IT WILL WORK </div> </> ) } export default ApiCalling;

Answer (score 0):

From your error, you can see it is due to the thumbnail property being missing.

You should make sure you only try and use the thumbnail if it exists:

```
{card.thumbnail && <Card.Img variant="top" src={`${card.thumbnail.path}.${card.thumbnail.extension}`} style={...} />}
```

Comment: Hey, you are right. there is a property of thumbnai, if the card.thumbnail is true, the <Card.Img variant="top" etc. /> will be executed. I added and i am seing the datas on console but the datas are not displaying on front-end. Because map probably is not working to get info on front-end. I am sharing the screen.

Comment: The codes look below now;

useEffect(() => {
        axios({
            url: "https://gateway.marvel.com/v1/public/characters?ts=1&limit=50&apikey=",
            method: "GET",
            })
            .then( result => {
                setStateCharacters({
                    characters : [result],
                    ...stateCharacters
                })
                const getInfo = result.data.data.results;
                getInfo.map((result) => {
                    console.log(result.thumbnail.path);
                })
            }) 
    },[])

Comment: const RenderCard = (card, index) => {
            return(
                <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }} key = { index }>
                    { card.thumbnail && <Card.Img variant="top" src={`${card.thumbnail.path}.${card.thumbnail.extension}`}
                   style={{ width:"100%", height:"200px"}} /> }
                         <Card.Body> 
                         { card.name && <Card.Title>{card.name}</Card.Title> }
                            <Button variant="primary">More Information</Button>
                        </Card.Body>
                </Card> ) }

Comment: return (
            <>
           
            <div className="card-heros__title">MARVEL CHARACTERS</div>
                <div className="card-heros">
                    I NEED TO CALL getInfo COMPONENT IN HERE THEN I WILL NEED TO WRAP IT WITH RenderCard then I BELIEVE IT WILL WORK
                </div>
        
    
            </>
        )
}

export default ApiCalling;